# reading utmpx without FILE* in c

Tags: c

I'm having a issue with my program I want to read in the users from the utmpx file and output it but I keep getting strange output.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <utmp.h>
#include <utmpx.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
//open the Utmp file
// mine is different because I have mac so it is utmpx

void utmpprint(struct utmpx *log);
int openUtmpFile();
int main()
{
    struct utmpx buffer[5];

    int tmpfile = openUtmpFile();

    if (tmpfile < 0)
    {
        printf("Error opening utmpx file");
        return -1;
    }
    read(tmpfile, &buffer, sizeof(struct utmpx));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%s", buffer[i].ut_user);

    return 0;
}
int openUtmpFile()
{
    int tmp = open("/var/run/utmpx", O_RDONLY);
    printf("%i", tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

Output:3utmpx-1.00Pwv��%

Comment: OT: regarding the prototype: `int openUtmpFile();`  when writing a prototype for a function that takes no parameters, place `void` between the parens so the compiler produces code that takes no parameters; otherwise, the compiler produces code that can take any number of parameters, (including zero parameters)

Comment: OT: regarding: `read(tmpfile, &buffer, sizeof(struct utmpx));`  and `int tmp = open("/var/run/utmpx", O_RDONLY);`  Always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Error opening utmpx file");`  when outputting an error message it should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` suggest: `perror( "open failed" );` which also outputs to `stderr`, the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Answer (score 3):

In this part

```
    read(tmpfile, &buffer, sizeof(struct utmpx));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%s", buffer[i].ut_user);
```

you read only one element and then print five elements.

Second elements and later are not initialized.

To read five elements, multiply `5` to the size to read:

```
    read(tmpfile, &buffer, sizeof(struct utmpx) * 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%s", buffer[i].ut_user);
```

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting unreadable output